# Why can't i send contact form to mail when i change click event to submit?

Tags: javascript, ajax, form-submit

```
  let btn = document.getElementById("formSubmitButton");
btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
```

//when i change click event to submit it just reloads the page nothing else

```
  e.preventDefault();
  let fullName = document.getElementById("name").value;
  let mail = document.getElementById("email").value;
  let subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
  let message = document.getElementById("message").value;
```

//fetch formsubmit.co

```
  fetch("https://formsubmit.co/ajax/faa319d2539aa327d6bbbbd5b5ac10c3", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      Name: `${fullName}`,
      Mail: `${mail}`,
      Subject: `${subject}`,
      Message: `${message}`,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});
```

Comment: There is no `**click**` event, or that just weird formatting on your part?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake when i submit question . Dont pay attention to it.  My question is why it does not send form with submit event?

Comment: a button doesn't have a submit event - you would need to add it to the form instead see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event